# Mac mini (Late 2014) に Ubuntuをインストールしたが、Wi-Fi アダプタが認識されない

Tags: ubuntu, mac-mini

先日MAC mini 2014をゲットしまして、どうせならLinuxをインストールしてみようとたのですが、Setting > Wi-Fiに No Wi-Fi Adapter Found が表示され困っております。

Mac miniのWi-Fiアダプタを認識してほしいのですが、何かアドバイスをいただけないでしょうか。

以下に環境とやったことを記載します。

**環境:**
Mac mini (Late 2014)
Ubuntu Desktop 22.04.3 LTS
現在：有線LAN (無線LANが使えるようになりたい)

##### やったこと

下記のコマンドを実行した後に再起動しても依然としてアダプタが見つからないと言われる。

```
sudo apt update
sudo update-pciids
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
sudo reboot
```

**追記:**
Wi-Fiの認識についてはこちらを参考に致しました。
[古い MacBook に Ubuntu 20.04 LTS をインストールした際に WiFi が利用できない問題を解決する](https://pslabo.hatenablog.com/entry/2021/02/14/222753)

Mac miniへのUbuntuのインストールはこちらを参考に致しました。
[Mac Mini にLinuxをインストールしてみました。](https://rockstream-jp.com/mac-mini-linux-install/)

以上です。少しでもアドバイス頂けましたら幸いです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 参考: [Wi-Fi not working on mid 2014 MacBook Pro with Ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/q/748951/902344)

Comment: ありがとうございます！！！無事解決できました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cubick様のアドバイスで解決いたしました。

以下、実行後に再起動でwifiを認識しました。

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --reinstall install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl brcmfmac brcmsmac bcma
sudo modprobe wl
```